# ambiguous function template

Tags: c++, templates, enable-if

I want to select a specific function template via enable_if applied to the return type.

A boiled down example would be to distinguish between signed and unsigned arguments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_signed_v<T>, bool>
foo(T t)
{
  return true;
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_signed_v<T>, bool>
foo(T t)
{
  return false;
}

int main(){
  std::cout << foo<uint32_t>(42) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

here I get the compiler error: `call of overloaded ‘foo<uint32_t>(int)’ is ambiguous
   std::cout << foo<uint32_t>(42) << std::endl;`

I get that it would be ambiguous if I used `foo(42)` as 42 can be converted to signed an unsigned. But if I specify the tempalte parameter explicitly as in my example I would expect it to work.

What is the problem with my code and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are missing the `::type` at the end of your `enable_if` so no error occur even when the condition is false

you can use `enable_if_t` or add the `::type` like

```
typename std::enable_if<std::is_signed_v<T>, bool>::type
```

Answer (score 1):

As Tyker already answered you're missing `::type` from `enable_if`.

By the way you could reduce the amount of boilerplate by using `std::enable_if_t` ([since C++14](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if))

```
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed_v<T>, bool>
foo(T t)
{
  return true;
}

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_signed_v<T>, bool>
foo(T t)
{
  return false;
}
```